# Extracting data from json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a very basic clarification about json object adding and removing the data.

Consider the following example

```
var mainobject = JSON.parse('[{"Innerobject1":[{"Name" :"Xavier","Dup":"B"},{"Name" :"Gh","Dup":"B"}]},{"Innerobject2":[{"Name" : "Cat","Dup":"C"},{"Name":"Dog", "Dup":"D"}]}]');

var seen = {};

mainobject.forEach(function(inner_arr) {
Object.keys(inner_arr).forEach(function(k)
{
   inner_arr[k].forEach(function(obj) {

       if (seen[obj.Dup]) {
           obj.Dup = "";
       }

       seen[obj.Dup] = true;
       //alert(seen[obj.Dup]);
       //alert(seen.(obj.Dup));
    });
});
});
alert(JSON.stringify(mainobject, 0, 4));
```

In the example above,

`alert(seen[obj.Dup]);` gives the value as **true** 
whereas `alert(seen.(obj.Dup));` doesnt give me any value .
My understanding is , when we have a json object , `object.key` should give me the value.

In the same idea, `seen.(obj.Dup)` should have ideally given the alert as "true" because seen is a json object.
Is the object converted to an array at runtime?

Comment: Please, read about the use of brackets in objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: `seen.(obj.Dup)` isn't valid syntax so not sure what you are expecting. If you want to use dot notation, you have to use a string, not a variable

Comment: On top of what @Wolff said, even using strings, if your string is not a valid name (e.g. "this is an invalid name"), you'll have to use bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `alert(seen[obj.Dup])` you are in fact printing `seen[obj.Dup]` and it will always be true because you are setting it as true on the line before.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but at the end of the execution your dictionary `seen` equals to this `{B: true, "": true, C: true, D: true}`

I think you may have a confusion with dot notation.
If you have

```
a = {'b': 'c', 'd': 'e'};
b = 'd'
// a.b == 'c'
// a[b] == a['d'] 
// a[b] == 'e'
```